# Linux how do I put double quotes around a file before piping it to tar?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, tar

I use ls to obtain my filename which has white space so it looks something like:

`my file with whitespace.tar.bz2`

I want to pipe this to tar similar to:

```
ls | grep mysearchstring | tar xvjf
```

How can I insert double quotes before piping it to tar?

Comment: I do not think that your question is asking the right question.  Your "similar to" example will not actually open any files from the directory.

Answer (score 7):

A good tool for this is find and xargs.  For example, you might use:

```
find . -name '*.tar.bz2' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 tar xjf
```

As pixelbeat suggested you can also use the shell like this:

```
for archive in *.tar.bz2; do tar xvjf "$archive"; done
```

Comment: find | xargs is the most general, and performant.
For pure shell the following will handle whitespaces:

for archive in *.tar.bz2; do
    tar xvjf "$archive"
done

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with shell-wildcard expansion?  (Assuming there is only one filename.)

```
% tar -cvf   *mysearchstring*
% tar -xvf   *mysearchstring*
```

Sure, the filename that matches *mysearchstring* will have spaces.  But the shell [tcsh,bash] will assign that filename, **including its spaces**, to a single argument of tar.

You can verify this with a simple C or C++ program.  E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  cout << "argc = " << argc << endl;
  for ( int i = 0;  i < argc;  i ++ )
    cout << "argv[" << i << "] = \"" << argv[i] << "\"" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Try it:   **./a.out *foo***

This is why CSH has the :q [quoted wordlist] option...

E.g. [tcsh]

```
foreach FILE ( *mysearchstring* )
    tar -xvf $FILE:q
end
```

Or *tar -xvf  "$FILE"* instead of *tar -xvf $FILE:q*, if you prefer.

---

If you really must use *ls*...

Using *ls* piped through anything will output one filename per line.  Using *tr* we can translate newlines to any other character, such as null.  *xargs* can receive null terminated strings.  This circumvents the spaces problem.  Using *-n1* will overcome the multiple files problem.

E.g.:  \ls | grep mysearchstring | tr '\012' '\0' | xargs --null -n1 tar -xvf

**But I don't believe *tar* accommodates multiple tarfiles from stdin like the OP has it...**